# is there a way to trace all imports of a Java class

Tags: java

If I have a java class with 3 imports, I want to go in each imported class and see what class they import, and so forth while printing the results... any easy way to do this?

similar to mvn dependencies:list I suppose

edit: the context is that I want to know what is required to run this project at a bare minimum if I were to move/reuse it else where

Comment: I think if you run your program with the `-verbose:class` option it will print out all loaded (i.e., imported) classes.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Note the imports are on source level only, all compilers change them to explicit name. As `java.lang.String s;`.

Comment: The very obvious way to do it would be to write a program that scans your src directories which collects the list of imports and then goes and finds them in the appropriate places and then basically repeats. Find an import, find its .java file, get the import list, and repeat. This obviously would rely on those source files using import statements.

Comment: This question is no different from saying "How do I search a text file for some content". It's too broad.

Comment: You may not get all of the dependencies this way. In some places some class may be referenced with its fully qualified name (java.lang.String). Also many frameworks use reflection to be able to do their job and don't declare any imports for classes they may deal with. You should elaborate what you need in more detail, otherwise I think you will not get a useful answer.